# datepicker in not not working though used jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My `datepicker` form field is not working though I have used jQuery.

In the console it shows an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I have already googling upon it and place my jQuery to the top of the script. But still doesn't work

**HTML datepicker field**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <label>{{ trans('misc.deadline') }}</label>
        {{-- <div class="input-group-addon addon-dollar"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div> --}}
        <input type="text" value="{{ old('deadline') }}" id="datepicker" name="deadline" class="form-control" >
      <span class="help-block">{{ trans('misc.deadline_desc') }}</span>

    </div>
```

**script in `head` section**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**script**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  startDate: '+7d',
  language: 'en'
});
```

Anybody help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to load jquery before the datepicker library

Answer (score 1):

You need add Jquery befor Jquery UI and also add css for datepicker like this

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
  startDate: '+7d',
  language: 'en'
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <label>{{ trans('misc.deadline') }}</label>
        {{-- <div class="input-group-addon addon-dollar"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div> --}}
        <input type="text" value="{{ old('deadline') }}" id="datepicker" name="deadline" class="form-control" >
      <span class="help-block">{{ trans('misc.deadline_desc') }}</span>

    </div>
```